# RobotFramework+selenium cannot click the img button

Tags: python, selenium, automation, robotframework

**test cases from robotFramework:**

```
        Wait Until Element Is Visible    //input[@value='Data Solutions']
        Wait For Condition    return window.document.querySelector('[value="Data
    Solutions"]').style.visibility != "visible"
        Click Button    //input[@value='Data Solutions']
        Click Link    css=input[value='Data Solutions'] + i
        Wait Until Element Is Enabled     ${ticketServiceSelect}    #next text input field should be enabled
```

**source html page code:**

```
<div class="btn-group ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" bs-radio-group="" data-toggle="buttons">
<label class="btn service-icon ng-binding ng-scope" btn-radio="'Data Solutions'" ng-repeat="service in serviceGroups.itsmServiceGroups" style="">
<input class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid" type="radio" value="Data Solutions" bs-radio="" ng-model="ticket.serviceGroup" name="75">
<i class="dna-icon dna-icon-data-solutions"></i>
Data Solutions
</label>
</div>
```

Why selenium only focus on element not press the button?

Comment: why do you think it's not pressing the button? Are you getting an error? Are you getting unexpected behavior? Does the keyword say it clicked but nothing happens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RadioButton is not a <kbd>Button</kbd>. Use `Click Element` or `Select Radio Button` instead.

Comment: I'm also try this workaround: 

`Execute Javascript     window.document.querySelector('[value="Data Solutions"]').click()`


Works fine for me. Thanks!